# Connect to mysql database using ssh gateway in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, ssh, gateway

I want to connect to mysql database which resides in server1 using the gateway

```
  pid = fork { exec("ssh -N -L #{port}:#{ip}:3306 server1) }
  gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('server1', 'username')
```

By using the above command, i get process id and gateway object. How can i connect to mysql database using the pid and gateway.

I haven't much knowledge about gateway. It would be more helpful if anyone guide me through step by step procedure to connect mysql database(with sample mysql queries).

Comment: If you want to connect to mysql db running in different machine. 
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2 use this gem to connect.

Comment: @Saravanan How do i connect mysql db connection using gateway and pid.

Comment: Just doubt., why you have to use the gateway to connect to mysql?

Comment: mysql db resides in a private server.so i need gateway to connect to db.